# How do i display a new list after another list in Android

Tags: java, android

Say were talking about body parts and workouts.

I want to show the chest when its clicked it shows a list of workouts:

```
String[] bodyPart = { "Chest"};

String[] chestsWorkout = {"Bench", "Pushups", "Pullups", 
    "Incline bench", "Decline bench"};
```

Comment: Im not sure how to use that.

Comment: Did you read the documentation or look at any examples via a cursory Google search?

Comment: @MikeRetland Plenty of examples online. And a `Map` is one of the most important data structures in computer science. It's a good opportunity to learn it very thoroughly.

Comment: I read a little. It only shows how to show one list, not multiple ones.

Comment: @Kon Does is work with Android Studio?

Comment: @MikeRetland Yes, a Map is a Java concept.

Comment: not clear , whats your exact requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very simple way to do it. You can put many options along with `chest` in that string array bodyPart and you can create relevant string array like `chestsWorkout` for particular bodyPart. You can check which bodyPart user has clicked and then you can pass relevant string array like `chestsWorkout` with intent.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.opnanotherlistexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String[] bodyPart = { "Chest", "Legs" };

    String[] chestsWorkout = { "Bench", "Pushups", "Pullups", "Incline bench",
            "Decline bench" };
    String[] legsWorkout = { "walk", "run"};

    private ListView listNew;
    private ArrayList<String> newarraylist;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listNew = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNew);
        newarraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bodyPart.length; i++) {
            newarraylist.add(bodyPart[i]);
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, newarraylist);
        listNew.setAdapter(adapter);
        listNew.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String clickedItem = newarraylist.get(position).toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        SecondActivity.class);
                if(clickedItem.toLowerCase().equals("chest")){
                    intent.putExtra("parameters", chestsWorkout);
                }else if(clickedItem.toLowerCase().equals("legs")){
                    intent.putExtra("parameters", legsWorkout);
                }
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
package com.example.opnanotherlistexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView listAnother;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arraylist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);
        listAnother = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAnother);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("parameters")) {
            String[] params = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("parameters");
            arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                arraylist.add(params[i]);
                Log.e("balvier", params[i]);
            }
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arraylist);
            listAnother.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

opnanotherlistexample manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.opnanotherlistexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```